# Workaround for not being able to create links to edit From Responses in MS Forms

Tags: power-automate

I want to move over from another Online Form platform that gave me the capability to create links to edit form submissions so that people can update their responses in automated emails that was sent to them. As Microsoft doesn't have this ability I'm trying to use Flow in Power Automate to create a work around.

I am sending out emails from the excel sheet and the receiver should be able to at least update 1 of 2 possible values in that same response in the excel sheet. But I don't know how to get that person to trigger another flow. Or am I on the wrong path?

Comment: You will need a separate interface to trigger the flow. That interface can be access to the Excel spreadsheet, a SharePoint list or document library, or a web form you make (among other options). See more on Trigger options here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/triggers-introduction

Comment: Is it possible to insert a button trigger into the original mail though?

Comment: If you have that button perform an action that is supported as a trigger (e.g. fire an email, update a file in a list, etc), then yes.